# Bamboo - Docker image run Error - Connection refused

Tags: python, docker, flask, connection, bamboo

I am using bamboo to run the python application(Flask app).
And successfully check out the source code from repository and created docker image using bamboo itself.
And tried to run the image using bamboo docker task got below `Connection refused` error.
How do I solve this issue.

```
Failed connecting to http://localhost:5000, error: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    Attempting connection to http://localhost:5000
     Failed connecting to http://localhost:5000,  error: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    Attempting connection to http://localhost:5000
    Failed connecting to http://localhost:5000, error: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    Attempting connection to http://localhost:5000
    Failed connecting to http://localhost:5000, error: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    Attempting connection to http://localhost:5000
    Failed connecting to http://localhost:5000, error: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Docker file:

```
FROM python
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r python_modules.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: can you share your docker file?

Comment: How do you run the docker task? you can also specify the port open when running container. this could be part of bamboo environment setup.

Comment: @bamdan: yes, I already added.

Comment: can you show the command you use to run the task? you need to map the container port to the actual port like so. docker run -p 5000:5000. Although I'm unsure how you run it without seeing it.

Comment: I checked the log, '/usr/local/bin/docker run --detach --name myapp -p 5000:5000 myapp'

Comment: are you using docker-compose or docker-machine?

Comment: I am using Docker machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the docker file this looks as though the port is not open.

- you need to explicitly expose the port via the dockerfile
- you can change the entrypoint aswell.
- you need to have the following in the dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT python app.py
EXPOSE 5000
```

Comment: @bamdam: I have modified question with, docker file content. How do I expose the port

Comment: great add the line of code in the answer above and see if it works.

Comment: I run using Bamboo.

Comment: Added a docker task for run the container.